# Reference for Markov chains that uses ergodic theory definition of ergodic

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

I'm looking for a reference on Markov chains that at least handles discrete time, countable state space (not just finite state space), that uses the ergodic theory definition of ergodic (shift operator is ergodic measurable transformation) instead of the more common probability definition (irreducible, aperiodic, positive recurrent). Can you recommend one or more references?

Comment: Roughly speaking, the fundamental theorem of Markov chains is that the two definitions are equivalent...

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, because the whole point of this usage of the term is that if you have an ergodic (in the probabilistic sense) Markov chain, then its sample paths are a.s. ergodic (in the dynamical systems sense) with respect to the invariant distribution. But that means you need the invariant distribution in hand in the first place to make sense of this, and this very theorem is needed to ensure its existence.

Comment: @Ian To discuss ergodicity of a Markov chain in any sense, you need an invariant measure. Specifically, let $E$ be a sample space, let $(X_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a Markov chain on $E$, and let $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb P_k$ be the law of $(X_n)_{n\ge0}$ and $X_k$ respectively. If the shift operator is ergodic with respect to $\mathbb P$, then it is in particular probability preserving, which implies $\mathbb P_i=\mathbb P_j$ for all $i,j$, i.e. the initial distribution $\mathbb P_0$ is invariant.

Comment: @Jason Sure, but the point of this theorem is to furnish the invariant measure in the first place. Starting from the dynamical systems definition of ergodicity somehow misses the point that what we *want* is the invariant measure and what we can *check* is usually these sufficient conditions. To me it would be pedagogically awkward to start from the dynamical systems definition of ergodicity, say you want this, and then state the usual sufficient conditions.

Comment: @Ian I get the feeling we're actually trying to say the same thing - I originally thought you were disagreeing with Nate Eldredge and arguing that the dynamical systems definition is more general.

Comment: @Jason I was actually disputing the sentiment of the question. In the end the two are ultimately equivalent, as Nate Eldredge said. But I find it pedagogically awkward to start with the desired result and then proceed to identify sufficient conditions. That's not always true of course, but here I think it is, because part of the point is that at least in the finite state space case, ergodicity is almost automatic: the irreducibility assumption is somehow just specifying the kinds of problems that we're even talking about, and aperiodicity is a quite mild assumption on top of that.

Comment: @NateEldredge they are definitely not equivalent. For finite state spaces one means irreducible and the other means irreducible + aperiodic.

Comment: In probability, "irreducible, aperiodic, positive recurrent" is not the _definition_ of ergodicity.  A Markov process is _ergodic_ (in the sense of probability theory) if it has a unique stationary measure that attracts any other measure.  It just happens to be the case that in case of discrete-time countable-state Markov chains, ergodicity is equivalent to the condition that the Markov chain is irreducible, aperiodic and positively recurrent.

It is unfortunate that the term "ergodic" is used with different meanings in probability theory and in ergodic theory, but such is life ...

Comment: @Blackbird It's not as unfortunate as it sounds though, because as I was saying, the sample paths of an ergodic Markov chain are a.s. ergodic (in the sense of dynamical systems) with respect to the invariant measure. But that statement already has the invariant measure built into it, which we don't have for free in Markov chain theory. So you can make this connection after you've already proven what Nate called "the fundamental theorem of Markov chains", but it would be strange to make it first.

Comment: @Ian But in order for the unique invariant measure on the path space be ergodic in the sense of dynamical systems, it is sufficient that the Markov chain is irreducible and positively recurrent.  The extra assumption of aperiodicity implies strong mixing of the unique invariant measure in the sense of dynamical systems.

Comment: @Blackbird I see, so probabilists say "ergodic" when they mean something like "strongly ergodic". That is a bit more unfortunate.

Comment: For the record, all this confusion we are having in the comments is exactly why I want a good reference that puts all this to bed :)